# Query execution time double up when I select top N rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

This is my simplified query:

```
select 
    field1, field2, rn 
from 
    (select 
         field1, 
         field2, 
         row_number() over(order by idx desc) as rn 
     from   
         MyTable
     where 
         <where-condition>) as ttt 
where 
    rn between 0 and 10
```

This query has an execution time of 6 seconds. The strange fact is that if I execute only the inner select, the execution time is 3 seconds: therefore selecting the top 10 rows takes half the execution time, and this is quite strange.

Why am I getting this strange behaviour? I expected the  outer select to be the quickest operation, instead it is taking 50% of execution time

Edit:

Here it is the comparison among the execution plans: the upper plan is the execution plan without outer select, the plan in the bottom of the image is the execution plan including outer select

[image: compared execution plans. Down: with outer select, Up: without outer select]

Comment: It'll probably help to post the execution plan so we can see what's occurring

Comment: Co.pare the actual execution plan for the before and after versions of the query. Understanding how ROW_NUMBER works, I suspect that `where rn between 0 and 10` is confusing the optimizer. Try changing that to `where rn <= 10` this should get you the same results but faster.

Comment: @Martin I have added comparison between execution plan with outer select and without outer select

Comment: @AlanBurstein using <= is the same, execution time doesn't change. Please have a look to compared execution plans in the edited question. It is a huge query, I'm having trouble to understand what it's going on

Comment: That's not a TOP query. That query calculates row numbers for all rows and then filters them. Use either `TOP N` or `ORDER BY .. OFFSET .. FETCH` for a more standard-compliant syntax

Comment: If you execute this query on a large table the server will have to spool the results into a temporary table before filtering them without benefit of an index.

Comment: @AlanBurstein - Sql Server can convert `rn BETWEEN 0 AND 10` to a `TOP` with a residual filter (which in this case all rows will pass). See the plan for `WITH T AS
(
SELECT number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) as rn
FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE rn BETWEEN 0 AND 10`

Comment: The addition of a `TOP` can add a "row goal" that changes the plan shape. Difficult to see from those blurry images if that is the issue here. You should upload the XML for the plan - e.g. to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @MartinSmith you are correct. I wasn't at a PC so I could not test my assumption. Interesting side note - I just started learning about and reading up on "Row Goals"... Paul White has a good series on this topic. https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals